# How does NVIC know what function to call on an interrupt (libopencm3)

Tags: stm32, arm

I'm trying to learn ARM programming on the blue pill and was looking at libopencm (I've HAL but i want to move to an opensource alternative). In the examples for the RTC, it sets up the rtc_isr() function. But what tells the NVIC that the interrupt vector points to that function? Do I have to name my function with **_isr()?  I've tried to go through the documentation for it but it doesn't say anything about how interrupts are handled in the the NVIC.

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rtc.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/pwr.h>
#include <libopencm3/cm3/nvic.h>

static void clock_setup(void)
{
    rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();

    /* Enable GPIOC clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOC);

    /* Enable clocks for GPIO port A (for GPIO_USART1_TX) and USART1. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);
}

static void usart_setup(void)
{
    /* Setup GPIO pin GPIO_USART1_TX/GPIO9 on GPIO port A for transmit. */
    gpio_set_mode(GPIOA, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ,
              GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL, GPIO_USART1_TX);

    /* Setup UART parameters. */
    usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 115200);
    usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
    usart_set_stopbits(USART1, USART_STOPBITS_1);
    usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX);
    usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
    usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

    /* Finally enable the USART. */
    usart_enable(USART1);
}

static void gpio_setup(void)
{
    /* Set GPIO12 (in GPIO port C) to 'output push-pull'. */
    gpio_set_mode(GPIOC, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_2_MHZ,
              GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL, GPIO12);
}

static void nvic_setup(void)
{
    /* Without this the RTC interrupt routine will never be called. */
    nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_RTC_IRQ);
    nvic_set_priority(NVIC_RTC_IRQ, 1);
}

void rtc_isr(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t j = 0, c = 0;

    /* The interrupt flag isn't cleared by hardware, we have to do it. */
    rtc_clear_flag(RTC_SEC);

    /* Visual output. */
    gpio_toggle(GPIOC, GPIO12);

    c = rtc_get_counter_val();

    /* Display the current counter value in binary via USART1. */
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        if ((c & (0x80000000 >> j)) != 0) {
            usart_send_blocking(USART1, '1');
        } else {
            usart_send_blocking(USART1, '0');
        }
    }
    usart_send_blocking(USART1, '\n');
    usart_send_blocking(USART1, '\r');
}

int main(void)
{
    clock_setup();
    gpio_setup();
    usart_setup();

    /*
     * If the RTC is pre-configured just allow access, don't reconfigure.
     * Otherwise enable it with the LSE as clock source and 0x7fff as
     * prescale value.
     */
    rtc_auto_awake(RCC_LSE, 0x7fff);

    /* Setup the RTC interrupt. */
    nvic_setup();

    /* Enable the RTC interrupt to occur off the SEC flag. */
    rtc_interrupt_enable(RTC_SEC);

    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see the arm documentation combined with the chip vendor documentation to see what interrupt and address are connected to what peripheral/chip interrupt.

Comment: You the programmer are ultimately responsible for getting the vector in the right place and enabling the right interrupt.

Comment: The nvic is just an interrupt controller in front of the processor to enable or not the interrupts through

Comment: you should run with no libraries just your own code this will make a lot more sense.

Comment: in the HAL or LL (and maybe this one), the ISRs are predeclared as "weak" somewhere (e.g. ****_startup.c) and are considered the default ISRs. read about the "weak" attribute. then, you have to redeclare the exactly named ISR in your code so it replaces the weak one the library provider declared. obviously, it has to be named exactly as the original,weak one.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad That makes sense. I found the NVIC file that defines the functions but they are void which confuses me more because the compiler doesn't complain about multiple definitions

Comment: the HAL is open source...

Answer (score 1):

usually the library provider, defines the ISR table in the startup file. they use a predefined scheme for better readability (e.g. [peripheral_name]_isr) and make some empty "weak" functions to fill it up. when you want to use an ISR, all you have to do, is to redefine the origianl "weak" ones and the linker prefers your "strong" functions to the "weak" attributed ones and ignores them. read about the weak symbol in wiki :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol

and here are the predefined prototypes as documented on the official website:

http://libopencm3.org/docs/latest/stm32f0/html/group__CM3__nvic__isrprototypes__STM32F0.html